# strange behavior of Php for loop prints/loop half times of the array and only even numbers

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, tcpdf

I am trying to loop 22 times but below code executes only 11 times

```
for($rn=0; $rn<22; $rn++){
        $html_content .= '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$rn.'</td>
        </tr>';
}
```

Output from above code:
0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20

but I want all numbers through 1 to 22. FYI I am executing above code inside TCPDF class.

**UPDATE-1 FULL TABLE CODE**

```
$html_content = '
        <style>
            .cellHeader{
                background-color: #1982EA;
                color: #fff;
                padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
            }
            .rowHeader{
                background-color: #1982EA;
                color: #fff;
                text-align: center;
            }

            table {
            border:none;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            }

            table td {
            border-left: 1px solid #000;
            border-right: 1px solid #000;
            }

            table td:first-child {
            border-left: none;
            }

            table td:last-child {
            border-right: none;
            }
        </style>
        <table cellpadding="1" border="0" style="border: 1px solid #000;" id="tblData">
            <thead>
                <tr class="rowHeader">
                    <th style="border: 1px solid #000;">ITEM #</th>
                    <th style="border: 1px solid #000;">PATTERN #</th>
                    <th style="border: 1px solid #000;" colspan="4">DESCRIPTION</th>
                    <th style="border: 1px solid #000;">QTY ORD</th>
                    <th style="border: 1px solid #000;">UNIT COST</th>
                    <th style="border: 1px solid #000;">LINE TOTAL</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> 
    ';

    $sql_po_lns = $conn->query("SELECT po_lines.*, invt_warehouse.* 
        FROM po_lines 
        LEFT JOIN invt_warehouse ON po_lines.item_no = invt_warehouse.item_no 
        WHERE po_lines.po_no = '$impPoNo'") or die("An error occured: ".$conn->error);

    //if(($sql_po_lns->num_rows/31)>);
    while($row_po_lns = $sql_po_lns->fetch_array()){
        $html_content .= '
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center; border: none;">'.$row_po_lns['item_no'].'</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">'.$row_po_lns['style_no'].'</td>
                <td colspan="4" style="white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;">'.$row_po_lns['description'].'</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">'.$row_po_lns['ord_qty'].'</td>
                <td style="text-align: right;">'.formatDollars($row_po_lns['cost']).'</td>
                <td style="text-align: right;">'.formatDollars($row_po_lns['ord_qty']*$row_po_lns['cost']).'</td>
            </tr>
        ';
    }
    $num_of_rows = $sql_po_lns->num_rows;
    $num_of_page = ceil($num_of_rows/31);
    $rows_needed = ($num_of_page*31);
    $blank_rows  = ($rows_needed - $num_of_rows);

    for($rn=0; $rn<22; $rn++){
        $html_content .= '
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; border: none;">'.$rn.'</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
            <td colspan="4" style="white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;"></td>
            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
            <td style="text-align: right;></td>
            <td style="text-align: right;"></td>
        </tr>';
    }

    $html_content .= '</tbody></table>';
```

**UPDATE-2 PROBLEM SOLVED**

Problem solved, Actually the problem was missing double quotes for style attribute of 5th `<td>` inside `for` loop. Thanks to everyone who tried to solve this question.

Comment: Close the `td` tag: `<td'`

Comment: Still it's working fine from my side. :)

Comment: Problem solved, Actually the problem was missing double quotes for style attribute of 5th `<td>` inside `for` loop. Thanks to everyone who tried to solve this question.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
$html_content = '<table>';
for($rn=0; $rn<22; $rn++){
    $html_content .= '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$rn.'</td>
        </tr>';

}
$html_content .= '</table>';
echo $html_content;
```

Comment: <table> tag was already there I just showed code inside for loop that causes the problem.

Comment: @MuhammadTarique Then you just need to close your <td> like ```<td>'.$rn.'</td>```

Comment: Then can you please write more PHP code where exactly you print this table? Because at my end it's working find and i am able to see all the 22 numbers in table.

Comment: Ok I m updating my complete table code in question

Comment: Great it would be helpful.

Comment: Full table code UPDATED in my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136593/discussion-between-maulik-savaliya-and-muhammad-tarique).

Comment: Problem solved, Actually the problem was missing double quotes for style attribute of 5th `<td>` inside `for` loop. Thanks to everyone who tried to solve this question.

Answer (score 0):

Two changes in your code

```
<?php 
$html_content = '<table>';
for($rn=0; $rn<=22; $rn++){
    $html_content .= '
    <tr>
        <td>'.$rn.'</td>
    </tr>';
}
echo $html_content."<table>";
```

?>

- You forget to opening and closing table tag.
- You have missing '>' in `td`.
- You have use `=` if you want to print number till 22

Thank!
This will help

Comment: Problem solved, Actually the problem was missing double quotes for style attribute of 5th `<td>` inside `for` loop. Thanks to everyone who tried to solve this question.